# Android - how to change barcode scanner view size?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make Barcode Scanner by following this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otkz5Cwdw38&t=127s).By following this video I am able to get app working. But as the barcode reader takes the entire page while the scanning cursor takes just around 40% of screen area. So I want to know if there is a way to Shrink the barcode and remaining space can be used to put some buttons or warning TexViews.
So basically I want to set width and height of QR camera view.So is it possible?

[image]

As it is clear that space outside of green square is waste and that's why I want to arrange it so that it comes in about 200dp*200dp in dimension.

Code is as follow:

```
package com.example.priyanka.qrbarcodescanner

import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.hardware.Camera
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.zxing.Result

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView

import android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private var scannerView: ZXingScannerView? = null
    internal var mcontext: Context? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mcontext = this

        scannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)
        setContentView(scannerView)
        val currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

        if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                requestPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(CAMERA), REQUEST_CAMERA)
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                if (scannerView == null) {
                    scannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)
                    setContentView(scannerView)
                }
                scannerView!!.setResultHandler(this)
                scannerView!!.startCamera()
            } else {
                requestPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    public override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        scannerView!!.stopCamera()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CAMERA -> if (grantResults.size > 0) {

                val cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                if (cameraAccepted) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(arrayOf(CAMERA),
                                                    REQUEST_CAMERA)
                                        }
                                    })
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showMessageOKCancel(message: String, okListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext!!)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show()
    }

    override fun handleResult(result: Result) {
        val myResult = result.text
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.text)
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.barcodeFormat.toString())

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result")
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which -> scannerView!!.resumeCameraPreview(this@MainActivity) }
        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit") { dialog, which ->
            val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult))
            startActivity(browserIntent)
        }
        builder.setMessage(result.text)
        val alert1 = builder.create()
        alert1.show()
    }

    companion object {

        private val REQUEST_CAMERA = 1
        private val camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The highlighted area is the focus area of the camera, so the decoder can work better, you may place items on top of the View witha  FrameLayout, but you still better to let the focus area in the same size and zoom as it is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the zxing embedded library with these gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0@aar"
implementation "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0"
```

And then put it in your layout like

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/qr_scanner_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/your_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/your_height" />
```

And then use it in your code like

```
DecoratedBarcodeView qrView = findViewById(R.id.qr_scanner_view);
CameraSettings s = new CameraSettings();
s.setRequestedCameraId(0); // front/back/etc
qrView.getBarcodeView().setCameraSettings(s);
qrView.resume();

qrView.decodeSingle(new BarcodeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
        Log.d("barcode result: " + result.toString());
        // do your thing with result
    }

    @Override
    public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {}
});
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for these libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded and https://github.com/zxing/zxing should lead to further documentation